# Show that for $z \in \Gamma^{*}_{R}$, $|e^{iz}|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Here is what I've been given

For $R>1$ let $\Gamma_{R}:[0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be the semicircular path given by $\Gamma_{R}=Re^{it}$

Here is what I have so far

$|e^{iz}|= |e^{i}||e^{z}|= 1|e^{z}|$

$|e^{z}|=e^{|Re(z)|}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

but I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 2):

$e^{iz} = e^{i(x+iy)} = e^{ix}e^{-y}$, so $|e^{iz}| = e^{-y} \le 1$ for $z \in \Gamma_R$. (Note that $\Gamma_R$ is a semi-circle in the *upper* half plane.)

Comment: but its for $\Gamma^{*}_{R}$ that it should be less than or equal to 1

Comment: @Adam: What do you mean by $\Gamma_R^*$? If ${}^*$ is complex conjugation, then the conclusion is false.